# PHP Imagick : RAF file not being processed

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I am trying to read a RAF file in php using Imagick but somehow its not working. I have looked into the formats supported by Imagick and RAF is listed.

I later tried to simply read RAF file and echo it out but still no luck.

I keep on getting this error:
Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'unable to open image `/tmp/magick-H2rs1zGJ.ppm': No such file or directory

I tried rendering a png file saved in the same directory and it worked but somehow its not working for RAF.

```
$imagePath = "uploaded.raf";
$imagick = new \Imagick($imagePath);
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean a Fuji raw file? If so, you must probably install the `ufraw` or `dcraw` delegate to process it. Try`identify -list delegate | grep -i raf`

Comment: Yes. But i am not using it on a command line. 
I am using Imagick along with php on a web based application. So all the conversions and processing needs to be done automatically online.

Comment: PHP or command line, you will still need the delegate.

Comment: You can also check the `ImageMagick supported formats` in `phpinfo()`. Also check first 16 bytes of the `.raf` file, as it should read '`FUJIFILMCCD-RAW `'

Comment: RAF is in the supported formats, i checked that earlier. Is there any other API or JS plugin using which I can convert RAF to  TIFF?

I would process the converted file along Imagick later.